# Sqlite create table error near "AUTOINCREMENT"

Tags: sqlite, create-table

When i run this create table query in sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE Device
(DeviceNO INT PRIMARY KEY, 
ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, 
IP TEXT, 
Port INT, 
DeviceGroup INT, 
Password TEXT, 
Type INT, 
IsAutoConnectDevice BOOL, 
IsAutoConnectAmin BOOL, 
Placement TEXT, 
PrinterName TEXT);
```

shows me an error like this

```
near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error:
```

whats the problem?
is there any way to create a auto inc field without make it primary key?

Comment: You have a  `DeviceNo` which is promary key, why need another column to autoincrement? SQLite autoincrements automatically the primary key

Comment: CREATE TABLE Device(DeviceNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IP TEXT, Port INT, DeviceGroup INT, Password TEXT, Type INT, IsAutoConnectDevice BOOL, IsAutoConnectAmin BOOL, Placement TEXT, PrinterName TEXT);

Comment: The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
get more detail about this https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `AUTOINCREMENT` a fields declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, and none others.

Comment: Since I was engaged with you and trying to help you solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898857/how-to-stop-this-eventemitter-memory-leak-warning?noredirect=1#comment84803318_48898857, it would have been nice if you left a comment before deleting the question so I know what happened.  It's kind of like you just hung up on me in the middle of a conversation where I was trying to help.